# Did a statue of Mary, mother of Jesus cry in St. Rita's church in Ja-Ela in Sri Lanka?

Tags: catholic-church, miracle

[According to what seems to be this Roman Catholic church's official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/1585422125085636/videos/330963214491273/):

> Official News :
>   A miracle did happen today with tears coming from a statue of Mother Mary,  during prayers.
>
> The church is closed now for security purposes. It will be reopened
>   tomorrow for general public.
>
> Let us all get together and pray with Mother Mary.
>
> God bless you all!

(The Facebook page I linked to also contains a video recording of the alleged miracle.)

The information has made its way to media in my country ([planeta.pl](https://www.planeta.pl/Ciekawostki/cud-na-sri-lance-figurka-matki-boskiej-zaczela-nagle-plakac), known for publishing stuff like UFO sightings or clairvoyants' messages, but it got republished by the news aggregation service [msn.pl](https://www.msn.com/pl-pl/wiadomosci/swiat/cud-na-sri-lance-figurka-matki-boskiej-zacz%C4%99%C5%82a-nagle-p%C5%82aka%C4%87-wideo/ar-AADYSR9?li=BBr5MK7), which is how it reached me; I only reached the church's Facebook page through Googling).

There are other alleged cryings of Mary statues in Sri Lanka; but I'm worried that a question about all of these would be closed as too broad, so I'm not mentioning them now.

Did the statue cry unexplainably?

Comment: there seems to be 2 seperate statues from that same church with weeping attributed to them:

https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/65915581_2061368924157618_3593311360869466112_o.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_oc=AQlA4GGLRhfbHfw6p0GkCZ8I-86vHMkqhQIDhTNx6TRHXDbv2GS1NTHi8P-YIG9wzcA&_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.xx&oh=c674dcbce6c14f2732a9c5a77373bb06&oe=5DC40B64

https://www.facebook.com/1585422125085636/videos/2217172828547831/

Comment: @Murphy Your second link is from April 20, while the claim I cited is from July 4, so I believe my question is unambiguous, if this is what you wanted to say. Interesting find though! ☺ This church does seem to have an attention-worthy history.

Comment: A single drop of water on the face of the statue doesn't mean the statue was crying.  Occam's Razor and all that.  Leaking water from the roof, moisture condensing in the air, deliberately placed, I can think of 1000 different reasons besides supernatural crying statues.

Comment: I'm puzzled why it can be noteable that a church claims something like this. Other religions might make similar claims and if if you take one of them seriously, why not all?

Comment: @JeromeViveiros It is noteable because it has made its way to media (planeta.pl can be disregarded, by msn.pl not really IMO). "*Other relitions might make similar claims and if you take one of them seriously, why not all?*" - Indeed, why not all? I can see no reason to not ask a question about a crying Buddha statue, if there is such a claim.